# How to create a new .txt file on Mac when using CLion

Tags: c++, file, clion, txt

How do I create a .txt file in cLion compiler?

Comment: just launch your editor and save.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer
control+click on folder

Comment: You can also mark your own answer as "solves this question".